# Am I a low tenor or high baritone?

Tags: voice, vocal-range, voice-training

So I feel like this question is asked alot but I genuinely feel like I am definitely one of these two. I have a lower speaking voice like the Ab2-G2 area, but also my speaking voice is some of my lowest full chest notes I can hit. But when I do a proper thorough warm up I prefer to sing in the higher areas like E4 then in my mixed voice like up in the 5th octave with ease until F#.
But anyway my chest range is F2-G#4, falsetto on a good day can go A3-C6. And whistle range can extend to about a Bb7. I also use ingressive phonation on low notes like first or even 0th octave. Like ~F0.

Any advice will be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What is it that makes none of the answers to the virtually identical dozens of the same question apply to you? It's similar to asking what running distance is best suited to you before starting to train. It's just the wrong order to make decisions. First train your entire range and once it is developed you'll find you'll lean towards things in your voice and the literature that interest you. You go from there.